# Divs won't expand to 100% width (on top of each other within another div)

Tags: html, css, expand, stacked

I have a header that is divided into a few parts.

First, it's divided into left, and right.

The right part is then divided into stacked top and bottom, or at least that's what I'm trying to do.

However, they won't show up (unless there's text or something.)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header_left">
        <div id="header_title">
            <p id="t1">TEXT</p>
            <p id="t2">TEXT</p>
            <p id="t3">TEXT</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header_right">
        <div id="right_top">x</div>
        <div id="right_bottom">x</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #header_right {
    height:100%;
    float:right;
}

#right_top {
    height:140px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    background-color:#FF0000;
}

#right_bottom {
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: `#header_right` is floated so it has no width of its own, it expands as much as its children. Its children are as wide as their parent. Circular dependency. What is the expected width of `#header_right`? Also post CSS for left hand columns.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **position:absolute** for the empty div's to display

```
position:absolute;
```

Comment: Add it to what? I've tried many variants of that and nothing worked.

Comment: set that property to the div's you want to display even if they have empty content.

Answer (score 0):

You should to add this:

```
#header_right {
    height:100%;
    float:left;  /*changed from right*/
}

/*added new class*/
#header_left{
    float: left;
    width: 97%;
}
```